# How to convert a given number into decimal cents

Tags: javascript

I am getting back a response to price like `2511` which is actually `25.11`, it didn't convert it in response. I want to add a `.` to the last two digits of a number so that I can convert it into cents. How can I do that? when I try diving the number by 100, it didn't work for numbers which have 00 in the last of them, so for like `100` I want to convert it into `1.00`, it will give `1` when divided by 100.

Comment: `number.toFixed(2)`

Comment: @SamuelLiew, when I have number such as 1441, and I do .toFixed(2), its output, like 1441.00. I don't want it like that, I want something like 14.41

Comment: @KScandrett, It didn't work either

Comment: @leith you need to divide it by 100 first. Then apply SamuelLiew's answer

Comment: @KScandrett, how? can you please show a working solution

Comment: `let num = 100; console.log( (num / 100).toFixed(2) );`

Comment: or, `let num = 100; num = num/100; console.log( num.toFixed(2) );` etc